# scraping url and title from nested anchor tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

This is my first scraper using scrapy.

I am trying to scrap video url, title from https://www.google.co.in/trends/hotvideos#hvsm=0 site.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class CraigslistItem(Item):
    title = Field()
    link = Field()

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "google"
    allowed_domains = ["google.co.in"]
    start_urls = [
        "https://www.google.co.in/trends/hotvideos#hvsm=0"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        #for sel in response.xpath('//body/div'):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.xpath("//span[@class='single-video-image-container']")
    items = []
    for sel in response.xpath("//span[@class='single-video-image-container']"):
        item = CraigslistItem()
        item['title'] = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()
        item['link'] = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()   
        items.append(item)
        print items
```

General walk through of what I am doing wrong would be much appreciable.

Comment: you won't get this working since a `POST` request displays these movie-list. 
Try using scrapy [form-request](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-usage-examples)

Comment: @Jathin: thanks, but i really could not get you. could you please elaborate

Comment: Eventhough you are giving request to this [url](https://www.google.co.in/trends/hotvideos#hvsm=0) to get the movie list, actually internally an `ajax-post-request` is triggered and to that request as a response you are getting the movie-listing in that page

Comment: you don't need any xpath to fetch data since the reponse itself is a json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the help `Scrapy` `FormRequest` to get it done.

```
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
import json

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "google"
    allowed_domains = ["google.co.in"]
    start_urls = [
        "https://www.google.co.in/trends/hotvideos#hvsm=0"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        url = 'https://www.google.co.in/trends/hotvideos/hotItems'
        formdata = {'hvd':'','geo': 'IN','mob': '0','hvsm': '0'}
        yield FormRequest(url=url, formdata=formdata, callback=self.parse_data)

    def parse_data(self, response):
        json_response = json.loads(response.body)
        videos = json_response.get('videoList')
        for video in videos:
            item = CraigslistItem()
            item['title'] = video.get('title')
            item['link'] = video.get('url')
            yield item
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but I did not understand code, could youplease add explaination? and why change in url name i.e. `https://www.google.co.in/trends/hotvideos/hotItems`